# Check if value is higher than a threshold if it is, replace by

Tags: python, numpy, keras

My goal is to take a list with my:

`predictions = [0, 0.2, 0.9, 0.7]`

If higher than 0.5 it should become 0 if not 1

I tried:

```
predictions = np.where(predictions>=0.5,1, 0).tolist()
```

But when taking first element it is:

`[0]`

And not only `0`

What is the best way to do what I want?

Comment: predictions = [0; 0.2; 0.9; 0.7] this should be comma separated ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list-comprehension:

```
[0 if i>=0.5 else 1 for i in predictions]
```

Attention: You said you want an entry to be zero if the original value is above 0.5. Are you sure about that? Or should it be zero if below 0.5?

Answer (score 3):

Just use the `np.array.round` method:

```
>>> predictions = np.array([0, 0.2, 0.9, 0.7])
>>> predictions.round().tolist()
[0, 0, 1, 1]
>>>
```

If you really need a list comprehension do:

```
>>> predictions = [0, 0.2, 0.9, 0.7]
>>> [int(i >= 0.5) for i in predictions]
[0, 0, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

If predictions is a list then making it a numpy array inside where works :

```
import numpy as np
predictions = [0.0, 0.2, 0.9, 0.7] 
newList = np.where(np.array(predictions) >= 0.5,1, 0).tolist()

print(newList)
print(newList[0])
```

output:

```
[0, 0, 1, 1]
0
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying results in this error : `TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'float'`

This error is because you are passing a list to the `np.where` function which takes an `np.array` instead.

Converting the list to a numpy array using `np.array(predictions)` solves the problem.

So in summary change your line to this and you'll get the desired output.

`predictions = np.where(np.array(predictions) >= 0.5, 1,  0).tolist()`

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I tried before asking it here... but in the wrong place. I tried `np.array(np.where...)`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the prediction is a numpy array

```
threshold = 0.5 
prediction=np.array([0,0.2,0.9,0.7])
prediction[prediction<=threshold]=0
prediction[prediction>threshold]=1
```

Note - change the > or >= symbols according to your needs